# Capturing the behaviour of "back" button

Tags: android

I have an app that consists of two activities: the "main" activity (M) and the "settings" activity (S). S can only be launched from M. The purpose of S is to modify settings which affect M. S has a "done" button that finishes the activity and goes back to M (through M's `onActivityResult` method, with an `Intent` that contains the new settings for M to apply).

My problem is: if I go back from S to M using the hardware "back" button (instead of S's "done" button) the system brings M to the top *without any knowledge of the modified settings*. Can this behaviour be modified? Ideally I would like to alter the behaviour of the hardware "back" button when S is on top, so that it cause S to finish (that way M would get the new settings).

If that's not possible, and more generally: what would you do you to have the settings applied on a "back" button pressing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply override `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // check if settings have been changed
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Since this is a "closing action" do the `super` call after you have done your other work.

Following up on comments left on blackbelt's answer (now deleted comments) you may want to consider, if you haven't already, asking the user if they are sure they want to exit without saving in case they went into settings and decided not to change anything. What if they press the back button because they decided not to save the changes? You may already have something in place for this like a cancel button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the subsequent comment.

I find it strange that it is not necessary to call `finish()` from  within `onBackPressed()`. It must be that the system finishes the activity after executing onBackPressed(). But then, the statement "The default implementation simply finishes the current activity" in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed() should be "The default implementation does nothing"

Comment: You're welcome. But the statement is correct as I see it which is why you don't have to call `finish()`. I haven't looked at the source for `onBackPressed()` but I imagine if you did then you would find that it does call `finish()` in some way not "after executing" but during execution of `onBackPressed()`

Comment: I didn't look at the source of `onBackPressed()`. I just overrode it without calling `finish()`, and it works. That's why I believe that the system probably calls finish() after onBackPressed(). Oh, perhaps the call to finish() is within `super.onBackPressed()`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by my last sentence. That's why this is in the statement "simply finishes the current activity"

Answer (score 2):

you have to override the `onBackPressed` from `Activity` and manage the same logic from the `done` button

Comment: sorry got confused you might be right in this context (according to the question). but this http://dhruvgairola.blogspot.in/2012/08/design-android-and-back-button.html. always bothers me http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html. So is it right to override back button functionality?.

Comment: I stand to my previous comment. Imo the beahvior is differnt and have to lead to differnt pattern. Sometimes people hold the past and thay do not want let it go

Comment: I think you also have to account for the severity of the actions and account for the lowest common denominator. If the user makes a couple settings changes that aren't significant and they will easily be able to detect that they weren't saved and can easily re-do then I don't think you should override. However, if they make significant changes then you certainly don't want someone to lose those changes because they accidentally pressed the back button or because they didn't understand its effects. But in general, I think popping up a box for confirmation is annoying and unnecessary

Comment: Also, saving or taking some action when the user actually wanted to go back can be reckless

Comment: @codeMagic still things change, and probably the best way to go is adapt (imo)

Answer (score 2):

You can also introduce a new java class to your package with static fields holding your settings.

Write to them as user changes settings & read from them as soon as in Activity's `OnResume()` method or later as needed.

Comment: That's a great idea! In this app I'm doing right now, which is almost finished, it's too late to change the approach now. But I think I'll go about it that way in the future; I like it better

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by overriding onbackpressed method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    //get your settings from your views
    intent.putExtra("setting1","on");
    intent.putExtra("setting2","off");

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above will do what you want, however:

Have you looked into using the built in android SharedPreferences? That way changes to the settings (made in S) will be stored to the device and then you can tell activity M to look at the settings and update appropriately in the onResume method. Plus the settings will be saved forever and it doesn't matter what happens to S.

Comment: Thanks. I do use `SharedPreferences`, but only to save the preferences when the main activity is being closed. I don't want to use it as a means of communication between activities, because I thought it might slow things down if I save to file more than necessary

Comment: Plus, i'm not sure `onResume()` is called on "back" pressing, is it?

Comment: Fair enough. You are probably right, I'm sure someone here knows more about which is quicker (intents don't seem to be the fastest things in the world either).

Comment: `onResume()` will be called, see [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) (another activity coming to the front will pause M, and then `onResume()` is the only way back).